# IOException when downloading file that is secured with username and password in Java

Tags: java, inputstream, httpurlconnection

**Issue:**

I want to download a file that is laying on our school servers at a given interval. The .xml file I want to access lays behind a login, but you can, at least in a browser, access the file without using a login by modifying the URL:

```
https://username:password@subdomain.domain.net/xmlFile.xml
```

But Java throws an IOException if I want to access the page. Other files like [this W3 example](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml) work without any problems.

My current code used for downloading files looks like this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

URL webServer = new URL(url);
//url is the specified address I want to access.
InputStream stream = webServer.openStream();
Document xmlDatei = docBuilder.parse(stream);

return xmlDatei
```

**Question:**

Are there special arguments or functions that I can use to prevent this from happening?

Comment: https://repl.it/@JeremyFlowers/XMLParserExample - does adapting this still give you issues? May have a few more imports than you really need. Just knocked it up online instead of via an IDE.

Comment: There is no [tag:fileinputstream] here. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: What `IOException` do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) to access your file.

```
        String webPage = "http://www.myserver.com/myfile.xml";
        String name = "username";
        String password = "password";

        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);

        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);

        try (InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {

            // preparation steps to use docBuilder ....

            Document xmlDatei = docBuilder.parse(stream);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. If anyone else has the exact same issue, you need to replace Base64.encodeBase64 with Base64.getEncoder().encode when using Java 8. :)